# Converting earth kilometers to radians in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert earth kilometers to radians. I know this question has been answered else where but all those answers does not seem to answer properly.

what i have done so far is:

```
$radians = $km / 6371; // 6371 is the radius of earth in Km
```

is this correct? or do i have to use meters ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is right.

"Earth radius is the distance from Earth's center to its surface, about 6,371 kilometers (3,959 mi). This length is also used as a unit of distance, especially in astronomy and geology, where it is usually denoted by R⊕ (R_\oplus)."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius

Comment: @RakeshShetty I thought comments were more for suggestions.

Comment: "is this correct? or do i have to use meters ?" was the question "This is correct" is the answer. Backed up with the wikipedia article and a quotation from it. I think this is a legitimate answer, bro.

Comment: This does answer the question.

Comment: so the units must be exactly the same? that's where i got confused thank you so much

Comment: Yes. in your case $km must be a value in kilometer otherwise it won't be correct. The only thing is $radius = is not correct it must be $angle or $radiants or what ever 6371 is the radius.